# Query works in the browser but not in iphone

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm trying to make a web site with Jquery, in chrome browser it works fine but if I test with the inspection option inside the browser if I select iphone 4 or 5 or 6 the only code works is the toggle nav bar and it does change the DOM once I scroll the site.

Any help ?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script>

x = 0;  
$(function() {


    $(".icon-menu").click(function(){
    $("nav").toggle();
    x = 0;  
});


        $(document).scroll(function(){
        $(".menu_txt").text( x=x+ 1);
        if (x > 30) {
        $("nav").hide();
        }
    });


    $(".company").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".name_question:eq(2)").offset().top - 55
    }, 2000);
});


});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML or a working fiddle of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't know what

```
$("html,body")
```

try this only

```
$("body")
```